# how do i get data from csv and put in variable and get only the value that i want

Tags: php, csv

**Example**

I have CSV  file that contains data of random number example data in CSV :

```
639123456789,73999999999,739222222222,839444444444,8639555555555....more
```

So, if I upload it, I want it to explode in a variable or in an array as long as I get the specific data. example of data I want to get is all 2 first line starting at 73 be extract so meaning all numbers that start with 73 only.

Example: 73999999999,739222222222

I have tried it by using only 1 number using split,substr and explode function but my problem is if the user input a CSV bulk data with no limit.

Comment: Please add the changes you have done in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use substr() and loop through your array deleting the elements that do not match.

```
$str = '639123456789,73999999999,739222222222,839444444444,8639555555555';

$array = explode(',', $str);  //Convert your string to an array.

$searchString = '73';  //Set the value your looking for.

foreach($array as $key=>$value){

  if(substr($value, 0, 2) != $searchString){  //This will test first two characters.

    unset($array[$key]);

  }

}


$array = array_values($array);

print_r($array);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 73999999999
    [1] => 739222222222
)
```

**Updated**

This will make a new array with only the numbers you want in it, leaving the original array untouched.

```
$str = '639123456789,73999999999,739222222222,839444444444,739222222222,839444444444,839444444444,73999999999';

$array = explode(',', $str);

$searchString = '73';

foreach($array as $key=>$value){

  if(substr($value, 0, 2) == $searchString){

    $results[] = $value;

  }

}


print_r($results);
```

Comment: Hi joseph but i dont want to delete the other data i just want to get the specific data that i want and throw it to other functions i want to get them to be separated how do i retrieve the other number?  but thanks this works.

Comment: Hi Joseph Thanks a lot! :)